# Unknown data appears

Tags: php, curl

I have simple post function and when i postData, strange text(data) appears
[image]
But i don't use any echo command, just don't get why it happens. So if i comment postData line, that text(data) disappears, so it's 100% problem in postData function, but i don't see it.

**Source**

```
$data = [
    "mode" => "pixel",
    "product_id" => 999,
    "partner_id" => $_COOKIE["suaff"],
    "params" => $_COOKIE["suid"],
    "phone" => $pID,
    "price" => 10,
    "name" => "1"
];
postData("http://somepost.url", $data); // if i comment this, that text(data) disappears
function postData( $url, $data ) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

Comment: $data = http_build_query($data); ?

Comment: curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false); I have false

Comment: @SLI Have you tried serializing the data as I asked?

Comment: @ka_lin just tryed it now, and my post request won't work any more.

Comment: @PaulCrovella Thank you, that helps me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, curl will output the response body to stdout, which is what you're experiencing here. If you want curl to output to something else, redirect it with `CURLOPT_FILE`. if you want curl to return the body instead of outputting it, set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to true. if you want curl to ignore the response data... there used to be a `CURLOPT_MUTE`, but it was removed, so... just set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to 1 and ignore the return value - or, if for performance reasons, you need something faster/less memory intensive, open a file handle to `/dev/null` (unix) or `nul`  (windows) and give it to `CURLOPT_FILE` (if you're downloading a 4GB file, and using the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER trick, **your PHP script will consume over 4GB of ram**, but if you set it to /dev/null, the size will not affect the ram usage at all)